# Problem with Jenkins running Robot Framework script

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I am trying to automate the execution of Robot Framework using Jenkins.
But when I run Jenkins I am receiving the error "Permission denied". You can see bellow the error's print screen.

Despite several attenpts Im not able to identify where this restriction is.
I have already include the Jenkins user as SUDO user, but the error is still there.
I also applied o CHMOD 777 /home/eduardo/.local/bin/robot but did not solve.

Can someone please tell me how I can identify where this restriction (Permission denied) is.
Thank in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to change the ownership with `chown` of this file to the `jenkins` user.

Comment: `robot` executable is inside of home directory of user `eduardo` and jenkins user is not able to reach it.

Comment: Hy Dani.. I did it (-rwxrwxrwx 1 jenkins eduardo 218 abr  9 16:37 /home/eduardo/.local/bin/robot) but did not solve.

Comment: Hy JaPyR I understand. But how to fix this..??

Comment: @Eduardo At first glance I see two options: 1. Installing robot system-wide 2. Installing robot for jenkins user.

Comment: @JaPyR First of all Thank for you suggestions. I did de first one and : Uninstall robotframework, Sikuli, Selenium, csvlib and installed all its again. The problem was solved.
Now I am facing the error "Initializing test library 'SikuliLibrary' with no arguments failed: Failed to get_keyword_names!" I will search  about it. however is your have some clues about it I will be glad. Many thanks